# Is it possible to replace early bound module

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6, interop

with newer code written in another language if the interface/GUIDs/etc are the same?

I am trying to do this as is detailed in the cousin post:

[Legacy VB6 app replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963219/legacy-vb6-app-replacement)

But I thought I would cut to the chase.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be possible using COM. That's not a very fun route to go (or stay) down. .NET can be exposed for COM interop, not sure if this is even a potential solution, though.

Comment: That is the route I have gone as the module I am trying to replace is COM. But I just can't make it work i just keep getting automation error even tho all the id's and call appear to line up.

Comment: @Joh H Could it just be an error with loading the replacement COM object such as wonky registry settings or other general failure? That is, can the replacement be loaded from a new context, such as PowerShell or a new project? (BTW, I think this violates the COM CLSID "guarantees" in so many ways.)

Comment: It could be any number of things. It would be useful if I could just get more information about from the error like what aspect of the interface doesn't match! What guarantees are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic won't help in this case, since you're talking about a VB6 app referencing a COM component that WAS in VB6 (or something else) but that you NOW want to be VB.net (or C#).

That said though, you should be able to do this.

You'll need to use OLEView (or something similiar) to generate the MIDL for the COM DLL you're replacing. That will give you the specific GUIDS for all the classes and interfaces defined in that DLL.

Then you'll need to code up you .net version of the DLL, specifing EVERY SINGLE GUID for EVERY class and interface.

You'll want to look at the docs for the .net attributes:

ComVisible
Guid
InterfaceType

and possibly a few more. These attrs allow you to specifically notate what GUIDS to use for what objects and interfaces in your dll.

Basically, what you're gunning for is when you generate the Typelibs for the two DLLs (the old and the new), you should end up with identical tlbs. If you don't, the new one won't be early bound reference compatible with the old one.

Comment: Thank you, you have confirmed the approach I have been taking.But how perfectly do they have to line up? For example my IDL coclass references in the new code all contain an interface to _Object whereas (obviously) the VB6 stuff doesn't. The correct interface is there also like [default] interface _BIBranchDetails;
Also how perfect is perfect? For example if the orignal IDL contains calls that I am not using; do they still have to be matched up? Also it has a call to 'SetData' that uses a 'RecordSet' object from VB DA do I have to match that up? or can I define an empty definition?

Comment: If you don't reference the class or interface in your VB6 app, you don't have to include it, and you can definitely include additional classes and interfaces (with different guids) without any problems. So, basically, you're right. They don't have to line up perfectly, just on whatever GUIDS the host program references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# 4.0's `dynamic` to solve many of such problems with the problems communicating with COM.

`dynamic` objects and optional parameters were introduced to ease some of these pains.

Comment: Does this help if the consuming environment is not .net? But the replacement module IS?